# PHP regex:Find all 6 digit numbers in a string that do not end in 00

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find all the 6 digit numbers in a string that do not end in 00.
Something like that
    `/([0-9]{4})([^00])/`   //i know this is wrong

so the string

> **asdfs dfg_123456_adsagu432100jhasj654321**

will give me

> **results=[123456,654321] and not 432100**

Thanks
Have a good day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind: `\d{6}(?<!00)`

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: You could also use lookahead, I suppose - look forward to see if there's not a zero zero, then match two digits.

Comment: @Jefromi: I think lookbehind is most natural. It's "match this, but exclude that", instead of "match this much, then lookaround, then maybe match some more".

Comment: Yeah, I agree, just throwing it out there. Would be more intuitive if there were a lot more to match after the excluded bit.

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing the character class.
Just like `[ab]` matches `a` *or*`b`, `[00]` matches `0` *or* `0`.  A single character class cannot match two characters at once.
`[^00]` matches a single non-zero character (such as `a`)

Instead, use the following:

```
/([0-9]{4})([0-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/
```

Comment: I don't think so. That'll match 1234ab.

Comment: Try to use `(?: )` to not include two chars to pattern: `/([0-9]{4})(?:[^0]{2})/`

Comment: Please test your answer here http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ with the string i gave you and you will see that is not producing the desirable result.